# Removal of Qgis 2.2 after 2.4 install, while keeping WFS and WMS features

Tags: qgis-2.4

Can i safely uninstall Qgis 2.2 after I've installed the 2.4 version and keep my WFS and WMS features?

I'd rather be certain, so I don't have to setup the whole thing again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, you have a save button in the top right corner of the WFS window (same for WMS).

Use it to export your WMS/WFS and load them on the new version of QGIS.

[image]